# how to create Equalizer Button in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to android i wish to create a button like a Equalizer Button. At the time of track the button i need to do some work.Can any one help me

Comment: What, exactly, is "a Equalizer Button"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the SeekBar. That's a View derived from the ProgressBar, but with a "thumb" so it looks like a slider control. A user can use the thumb to move left or right from min to max. You don't have to use it like a progress bar to track the progress of something, and can receive notifications that the user is touching and moving the thumb using a SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.